# How to extract chunks of XML?

Tags: java, xml

I've Big XML whose size could be varied from 1.5 GB to 1.5 GB +. Secondly I've one utility who process this XML. But In whole XML only few Inner tags are there which are responsible to produce Output from that utility.

Concern here is, If its a small xml it gets processed but in BIG xml I gets an error Java heap space.

I'm aware of whole pattern of XML and the sequence of inner tags as well who actually gets used to produce output. So I was thinking to extract only that required XML out of whole XML and complete the required XML with just outer tags but not with tags with Data. I've tested this with small data its working but am not sure how can I take out those chunks out of Big FAT XML.

Dont want to increase JVM parameters always unnecessary.

Is there any way I could do it and give those small XML chunks to utility ?
Can anyone share their views ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use DOM parsers for big XML files - use SAX one

Comment: @BorLaze, But do you think so they could give me the XML with tags ? I thought they expose only XML tag's values. Please correct me ..!

Comment: May be I understand your wrong first time. Is is correct to say - you have big input XML, with a lot of data in tags; but you don't require them all and want to left only several of them before sending to 'second utility'? I.e. from <root><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></root> you want to get <root><b>2</b></root>?

Comment: @BorLaze, <root><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></root> you want to get <root><b>2</b></root> ....YES

Comment: I see. You need XSLT transformation in this case. Do you know about it?

Comment: @BorLaze...Will it help ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187788/discussion-between-bor-laze-and-joy).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that XSLT processors will help you avoid problems with large XML files. Instead, I would suggest you should use a straming API, for instance StAX, which is intended to process each XML tag as soon as it is parsed.

Take a view to the [StreamFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html#bnbgh) example.